# Подсчет кол-ва дней Django

Tags: python, django, дата, калькулятор

Имеется проект написанный на Django.

В нем создана модель проекты.

В этой модели столбцы `date-start & date_end`.

Необходимо реализовать таким образом, чтобы подсчет был дней от начала до конца проекта с учетом сегодняшнего дня. То есть - есть 3 даты (01 01 2000 - 01 02 2000(это время проекта) и допустим сегодняшняя дата 15 01 2000).

Сейчас есть форма по которой высчитываются дни

```
def diff_date(self):
return (self.date_end - self.date_start).days
```

таким образом я вывожу общее количество дней на проект. Но как сделать так чтобы это общее кол-во дней выводилось с учетом сегодняшнего дня : То есть разница между датами 31 день. в итоге мне надо из 31 - 15 чтобы получить кол-во дней которое осталось.

Comment: отдельные вопросы задавайт, пожалуйста, отдельно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать с помощью datetime библиотеки

```py
import datetime

date_start = datetime.date(2020, 5, 1) # Начало мая 2020 (начало проекта)
date_end = datetime.date(2020, 6, 1) # Начало июня 2020 (конец проекта)

project_time = date_end - date_start # Количество дней для проекта
date_now = datetime.date.today() # Сегодняшняя дата
val1 = date_end - date_now  # Сколько дней до конца проекта от текущего дня
val2 = date_now - date_start # Сколько дней прошло от начала проекта до текущего дня

print(project_time, " | ", val1, " | ", val2)
```

Можно попробовать сделать так:

```py
from django.conf import settings 
from django.db import models 
from django.utils import timezone 

import datetime

class Project(models.Model): 
    date_start = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True) 
    date_end = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True) 

    def diff_date(self): 
        return (self.date_end - self.date_start).days, (self.date_end.date() - datetime.date.today()).days, (datetime.date.today() - self.date_start.date()).days
```

Про преобразование DateTimeField в datetime.date есть тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35300460/get-date-from-a-django-datetimefield

Comment: Вся проблема в том что даты будут разные , заполняются они при создании проекта , а также при редактировании .

Comment: Так работать можно с разными датами, не вижу проблемы, это просто пример как получить нужные вам значения

Comment: Возможноли что то сделать с этим кодом ?
`from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Project(models.Model):
    date_start = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    date_end = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def diff_date(self):
        return (self.date_end - self.date_start).days
`

Comment: попытался сейчас вывести сл.образом  ``date_start = datetime.date()``. Вышла ошибка pos1 - (year)

Comment: Добавил, попробуйте

Comment: ``Осталось : (121, datetime.timedelta(days=18), datetime.timedelta(days=103))`` Вот такой код выдается в дизайне . Видно что он считает дни от начала - до конца (121 день) , во вторую строчку передает 18 дней(это я так думаю осталось) и 103 дня прошло.

Comment: Поменял: добавьте в скобки и `.days`. 1 дата от начала до конца проекта, 2 дата от конца проекта до сегодняшнего дня, 3 дата от сегодняшнего дня до начала проекта

Comment: Спасибо. Разделил написанный вами код на три части , Всего - Осталось - Прошло. Все значения верны и корректны ) . Спасибо поставил, но не факт что отобразиться(

Comment: все таки у меня возникла еще проблема. Когда я пытаюсь вынести другие даты (у меня в итоге в карте преокта 4 даты (Основная дата проекта, Дата проектирования, дата снабжения, дата производства). Выдает ошибку когда пытаюсь поменять строчки `return (self.date_end - self.date_start).days` - на `return (self.proekt_end - self.proekt_start).days`

Comment: Какую ошибку выдает?  Попробуй: `(self.proekt_end.date() - self.proekt_start.date()).days`, чтобы преобразовать в дату формата datetime

Comment: `AttributeError at /
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'date'`

Comment: Тебе надо проверить правильно ли ты передаешь даты и передаются ли они вообще, скорее всего при передаче у тебя получается тип `None` и поэтому выходит такая ошибка. Сделать проверку `self.proekt_end is None` и сделай функцию после этой проверки `print("none")`, если в консоли выводится `none`, то стоит перепроверить даты.

Comment: Как мне это сделать ? если я сейчас сижу в manage.py shell , что мне надо ввести чтобы увидеть результат ? Просто вчера все эти же шаги делал, но с датой которая относится к проекту, все нормально было, но стоило скопировать код, как у меня начала вылетать ошибка

Comment: В функцию где возвращаешь `return (self.proekt_end - self.proekt_start).days` перед возвратом добавь `self.proekt_end is None:` на новой строке с табом `print("None")`. Потом при работе на сайте смотри в консоль разработки, сделай то же самое, что делал раньше, и посмотри в консоль, выводится `None` или нет

Comment: `self.proekt_end is None: return (self.proekt_end.date() - self.proekt_start.date()).days
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`